# Capistrano - machine name

Tags: capistrano

I have this task that downloads the production logs to my local machine.  It works fine if you have one machine running but if you have several the files will overwrite them selves.

```
namespace :log do
  desc "Get production log files"
  task :get_prod, :roles => :app do
    download("/home/user/myapp/shared/log/production.log", "log/production.log")
  end
end
```

I'd like to add some sort of identifier to the file name so it's unique but I'm not sure what to use?  Is there a capistrano variable that I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a special variable you can use. This variable ("$CAPISTRANO:HOST$") needs to be placed in the name of the destination file. Capistrano will interpolate it with the name of the host from which it currently transfers files.*****

Your code will look now like this:

```
namespace :log do
  desc "Get production log files"
  task :get_prod, :roles => :app do
    download("#{shared_path}/log/production.log", "log/production.$CAPISTRANO:HOST$.log")
  end
end
```

Please see that I also used the variable **shared_path** to make the code more DRY. It's a good practice to keep configuration in one place.

---

***** The source code for the string interpolation is in lib/capistrano/transfer.rb line 194 (in Capistrano 2.5.19):

```
...
def normalize(argument, session)
  if argument.is_a?(String)
    argument.gsub(/\$CAPISTRANO:HOST\$/, session.xserver.host)
  elsif argument.respond_to?(:read)
...
```

A general advice: If you try to find something first look in the internet and when you don' find it there quite fast, then look in the source code (it does not bite and allows you to know how the tool you are working with works).

Comment: @Pre-history thanks for the deploy_to/shared to shared_path refactor suggestion